# linq query with many-to-many relationship

Tags: linq

Let’s assume I have three tables in my database:

```
Authors(PK Id, AuthorName) 
Books(PK Id, BookName) 
Authors_Books(FK BookId, FK AuthorId)
```

I need to write a method which passes in a parameter int[] authorsIds and returns all books (Id, BookName, list of authors of this book) if it was written by any author whose Id contains in int[] authorsIds parameter.

I need LINQ query (query method).

I really need a help. Appreciate your help very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var int[] authors = { 1, 2, 3 };
var books = from book in books
            where book.Authors.Any(x => authors.Contains(x.AuthorId))
            select book;
```

PS: I assume `book.Authors` is your reference to `Authors_Books` table (or maybe has a different name).

Comment: Hi Cristian, thank you for your help but I think I will get only Book columns (Id, BookName). I need also to get AuthorsList - the list of authors for the book.

Comment: Please post your `Book` model.

Answer (score 0):

this answer is based on the exact structure without considering that A obj has B in its structure

```
var book = from b in books 
           where book.Id in ( from ab in AuthersBooks 
                               where selectedAuthers.contains(ab.AutherId)
                               select ab.bookId ) //now we have books that are authered by one of the selected authers
           select new { BookId = b.Id, // now we create an anonymos object to contain any info we need
                        BookName = b.Name,
                        BookAuthers = (from a in authers
                                       join ab in AuthersBooks
                                       on a.Id == ab.AuthersId
                                       where ab.bookid == b.Id
                                       select a)
```

this will propably have syntax errors and after correcting you may get an error about multiple threads which already has an answer here